# Selenium .GetAttribute("value") for Input is returning empty

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium

I have a web app using AngularJs.  I am testing it using specflow and Selenium. I had it working just fine till the other day I saw it failing on getting the values.  `element.SendKeys(value)` is working and I see the text in the textbox when it runs.

however when it calls `element.GetAttribute("value");` it returns an empty string.  I tried seeing if the value wasn't beeing set till it lost focus by sending a tab hit after the value but that didn't help.

I have been googling but everything I find says to use `.GetAttribute("value");` and thats what I am using.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The value attribute is most probably no set at the time you call .GetAttribute("value"). Try to wait for a value not empty.

Comment: I tried that, I used a WebDriverWaiter and waited for 5 seconds for it not to be empty

Comment: Are you able to get the value attribute through the console of the browser with the same selector?

Comment: yes, and I used chrome tools to verify that value is set

Comment: Could you show us HTML of the element?

Comment: I have the same issue over here. Selenium 3.3.1